# Display image from php

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to display an image in an html file. Up to now i used an url : http://placehold.it/400x300, it worked fine, now when i try to replace it with image from database it doesn't display anything. the image path is : D:/uwamp/www/project/upload/tcf_animal17.jpg i tried with different path but it doesn't work. i'm not sure where is the problem. i printed the data , this is the good path

html

```
 <?php foreach ($data[0] as $film):?>
            <div class = <?= $film['id_film'] ?> >
              <div class=  "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb filmDiv" >

                    <a class="thumbnail " id = "filmShow" href= <?= "/project/admin/showFilm/" . $film['id_film']?>>
                        <p> <?= $film['title_film'] ?> </p>
                        <img class="img-responsive overlay" src= <?= $film['img'] ?>  alt="">  

                    </a>
                    <a class="" href =<?=  "/project/admin/update/" . $film['id_film'] ?> >
                        <button name="upd" id="upd" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
                    </a>

                    <a class="delete"name= <?= $film['id_film'] ?> >
                        <button id="delete"  type="button"  class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controler :

```
public function GetLastFilms()
{
    $films = $this->film->getFilms();
    $lastFilms = $this->film ->getLastFilm();

    $dict[0] = $films;
    $dict[1] = $lastFilms;

    return $dict;
}

public function index() 
{   
    if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        $this->generateView($this->GetLastFilms());
    }else
    {
       header('Location: /project/admin/login');
    }
}

protected function generateView($data = array())
{
    $classeControler = get_class($this);
    $controler = str_replace("Controler", "", $classeControler);
    $view = new View($this->action, $controler);
    $view->generate($data);        
}
```

View :

```
public function generate($data) 
{
    $contenu = $this->generateFile($this->viewFile, $data);
    $racineWeb = Configuration::get("racineWeb", "/");
    $view = $this->generateFile('View/Template/index.php',
            array('title' => $this->viewTitle, 'contenu' => $contenu,
                'racineWeb' => $racineWeb));
    echo $view;
}

private function generateFile($viewFile, $data) 
{
    if (file_exists($viewFile)) 
    {
        extract($data);
        ob_start();
        require $viewFile;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new Exception("can't find '$viewFile'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the full path to the image for example *http://www.example.com/my/path/to/image.png*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the path to the image in the database is stored as local path from your machine (`D:/uwamp/www/project/upload/tcf_animal17.jpg`), where for it to display correctly it needs to be a path relative to the root of your web server documents.

For example, if your web server document root is `D:/uwamp/www`, then the path of the image you need to store should be `project/upload/tcf_animal17.jpg`.

Of course if you can't get the image to be stored within the web root, then you always have an option to just dump the content directly, however it's really not a good idea, for performance reasons:

```
<?php
    $mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype(string $image_path));
    $data = "data:$mime;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_path)); ?>
?>
<img src="<?= $data ?>">
```

This code is very crude and does no error checking - you'll need to add that for a production-level application.